# Imported Javascript not working in jmeter from Badboy

Tags: jmeter, automated-tests, performance-testing, load-testing, badboy

I am getting some below errors. As I have been executing imported script into Jmeter from Badboy tool. Does anyone knw , wht steps I have been missed?

Is thr any way to executing javascript into jmeter from badboy?

Please refer diff screenshots.

Response code: 400
Response code: 405
Response code: 500

[image: 1]
  [image: 1]
  [image: 2]

Comment: Your screenshots are not visible. Unless you provide more elements I am afraid nobody can help you

Comment: can you show the request tab?

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that the chance you will be able to successfully replay recorded script is close to zero. Modern web applications widely use dynamic parameters for [CSRF protection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet), [client-side state management](https://dzone.com/articles/aspnet-server-side-state-manag), client tracking, whatever. The majority of load testing tools record requests "as is" so all these parameters which need to be dynamic are basically hard-coded. So my expectation is that you need to revisit your recorded test and add some **correlation** to it, the process looks as follows:

1. Record your test scenario one more time and compare generated scripts. All request parameters which are different needs to be correlated.
2. Correlation looks as follows:

   - Execute first request

     - Extract dynamic parameters using suitable JMeter [PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors)
     - Substitute recorded hard-coded values with [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) coming from the PostProcessor(s)
   - Execute second request
   - Repeat above steps unless your test will be doing what is supposed to be doing, you can verify request and response details using [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener. Also be aware that "green triangle" doesn't necessarily mean "success", you might be hitting login page all the time.
3. And last but not the least - don't forget to add [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) to your Test Plan.

As an alternative to BadBoy tool you can consider recording your test using cloud-based proxy service, it can export recorded scripts in "SmartJMX" mode with automatic detection and correlation of all dynamic parameters, see [How to Cut Your JMeter Scripting Time by 80%](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-cut-your-jmeter-scripting-time-80) guide for more details.

LoadRunner tool also has this [automatic correlation](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/lr/en/12.56/help/WebHelp/Content/VuGen/Correlation/AutomaticCorrelation.htm) feature so you can install [Community Edition](https://software.microfocus.com/en-us/products/loadrunner-load-testing/free-trial) which is free up to 50 virtual users and see what generated script looks like.